# Error while accessing EntityManager - openjpa - WAS liberty profile

Tags: java, mysql, openjpa, websphere-liberty

I’m currently working on a openjpa project on **WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile 8.5.5.7.** with database being **MySQL**

During runtime, when I'm trying to access the **Entity manager**, I get the error like:

> Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception  is: java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
>       at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:461)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.Exception: See nested Throwable
>       at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.Exception(ExceptionUtil.java:317)
>       ... 27 more
>   **Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManager;**
>       at com.ibm.ws.jpa.container.v21.internal.JPA21Runtime.createEntityManagerInstance(JPA21Runtime.java:104)
>       at [internal classes]

currently I'm using the following dependencies:org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-all-2.4.0

During deployment, I see the following stack trace

> [err] 458  appname  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-16] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.MySQLDictionary" (MySQL 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 ,MySQL-AB JDBC Driver mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )).
>   [err] 502  appname  INFO   [Default Executor-thread-16] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Connected to MySQL version 5.5 using JDBC driver MySQL-AB JDBC Driver version mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} ).

But this doesn’t abort my deployment process and I can still consume my services.

Added the following features to server.xml

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Assuming it to be a compatibility issue, I've used older versions of openjpa till 2.2.1.
Disabled jpa-2.1 feature from server.xml 
But No luck.

Any information/ reference/ solution to the above issue is much appreciated. Thanks

---

**Update:**
Thanks for the update.
Updated the server.xml as

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
</featureManager>
```

That still is Not able to pick the EntityManager.

> [ERROR   ] Error occurred during error handling, give up!
>   nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException while invoking public void foo() with params [].
>   [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage:116'
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException while invoking public void foo() with params [].
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
>       at [internal classes]
>   Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: 
> java.lang.NullPointerException while invoking public void foo() with params [].
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:167)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at **com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSIException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:124)
>       at [internal classes]**

Comment: try to remove `webProfile-7.0`, add `jpa-2.0` if you want to use that version and also remove jpa jars from your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified jpa-2.1, but OpenJPA does not support JPA 2.1.  The JPA 2.1 provider included with WebSphere is EclipseLink.  You either need to remove the references to OpenJPA from your persistence.xml and use the default EclipseLink (though there are some [known behavior changes](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_jpa21_behavior.html)), or as Gas suggested, you need to replace webProfile-7.0 and jpa-2.1 with jpa-2.0 if you want to continue to use OpenJPA.

Comment: Hi, this helped to an extent, but still I'm unable to pick entity manager.Please view the update where I see null pointer exception because, the EntityManager is Not getting injected to my Dao class.

Comment: @SashankNori The full stack trace is in messages.log.  Can you post that rather than the truncated one from console.log?

Comment: I observed that the feature jpa-2.0 was NOT installed or available as a feature on WAS liberty 8.5.5.7.
So manually installed using the command

**/wlp/bin/installUtility' install jpa-2.0**
This resolved the issue.
Appreciate your help in this.Thankyou!

Comment: @SashankNori Ah, sure, if you downloaded from wasdev.net (vs a contract from IBM), then all those downloads will be JavaEE 7 only.  Glad you figured it out!